# Is it possible to simulate a phone call on iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, phone-call

I am building an app that will make a phone call. How can I test this feature on the simulator?  I get no response when I call `openURL`. Though of course this does work on the actual device.

Also is it possible to know whether the iPhone is currently in calling mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry Pal. You cannot check it in on a simulator.

All the best.